# Matrix Operations with $(A+BC)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

so I know the rule
$$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$$
but is there any way to manipulate
$$(A+BC)^{-1}$$
I really am trying to get better at Matrix Operations so I am practicing below where all $n \times n$ matrices that are invertible from
$$({\bf I} + {\bf CD})^{-1} = {\bf I} - {\bf C}( {\bf I} +  {\bf DC})^{-1}{\bf D}$$

Comment: You'll need strong conditions on the matrices involved. For example let $C=A$ and $B=-1$ with $A$ invertible. $A,B$ and $C$ are invertible but $A+BC=0$ which is clearly not invertible.

Comment: See the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)